# How can I reinitialize my code

Tags: winapi, dialog

Hi I am currently working on a project where we are creating a UDP server to communicate with a KUKA robot. We are able to establish the connection with the robot and exchange the data back and forth but when an event occurs such as the robot faulting out due to motor over torque. So to detect this fault we have added a timeout to the code so that the main dialog box will close and reopen so that all the variables will be reinitialized and we can set the connection to reestablish.

Heres the server code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "HapticRobot.h"

#include "CMaths.h"
using namespace chai3d;


#include <winsock.h>
using namespace std;
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2.lib")
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

DWORD WINAPI DoGravity(LPVOID lpParameter);

#define REFRESH_INTERVAL  0   // sec

const int kBufferSize = 1024;
int nTempHold;

extern HapticDevice hd;
extern HWND g_hWndHapticBox;
extern bool bRobotInMotion, bRobotConnectInit, bRobotConnected;
extern Handles hc;
bool err;
std::string stSend, stSendXML, stLine;
std::string stRobotStatus , stAppend;
TCHAR *chRobotStatus;
//variables for timeout
fd_set fds;
int n;
struct timeval tv;

//// Prototypes ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

SOCKET SetUpListener(const char* pcAddress, int nPort);
bool EchoIncomingPackets(SOCKET sd);


//// DoWinsock /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// The module's driver function -- we just call other functions and
// interpret their results.


int DoWinsock(const char* pcAddress, int nPort)
{
    int nRetval = 0;

    ifstream inFile("HardDisk/ExternalData.xml");
    if (inFile.is_open())
    {
        while ( inFile.good() )
        {
            getline ( inFile, stLine);
            stSendXML.append(stLine);
        }
        inFile.close();
    }

    SendDlgItemMessage(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_LIST_Server, LB_INSERTSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)L"Establishing the listener...");
    SOCKET ListeningSocket = SetUpListener(pcAddress, htons(nPort));
    SendDlgItemMessage(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_LIST_Server, LB_INSERTSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)L"Waiting for connections...");
    bRobotConnectInit = true;
    SetDlgItemText(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_STATIC_RobotStatus, _T("Waiting for robot"));
    while (1)
    {
        EchoIncomingPackets(ListeningSocket);
        bRobotConnected = false;
        bRobotConnectInit = true;

        SendDlgItemMessage(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_LIST_Server, LB_INSERTSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)L"Acceptor restarting...");

    }
}


//// SetUpListener /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Sets up a listener on the given interface and port, returning the
// listening socket if successful; if not, returns INVALID_SOCKET.

SOCKET SetUpListener(const char* pcAddress, int nPort)
{
    u_long nInterfaceAddr = inet_addr(pcAddress);
    if (nInterfaceAddr != INADDR_NONE)
    {
        SOCKET sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

        sockaddr_in sinInterface;
        sinInterface.sin_family = AF_INET;
        sinInterface.sin_addr.s_addr = nInterfaceAddr;
        sinInterface.sin_port = nPort;
        if (bind(sd, (sockaddr*)&sinInterface, 
                sizeof(sockaddr_in)) != SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            return sd;
        }

    }

    return INVALID_SOCKET;
}

//// EchoIncomingPackets ///////////////////////////////////////////////
// Bounces any incoming packets back to the client.  We return false
// on errors, or true if the client closed the socket normally.

bool EchoIncomingPackets(SOCKET sd)
{
    // Read data from client

    std::string stReceive;
    std::string stIPOC;

    std::wstring stTime;
    int nStartPos, nEndPos;
    char acReadBuffer[kBufferSize], acWriteBuffer[512];
    int nReadBytes;

    struct sockaddr_in clientAddr;
    int sockAddrSize = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);


    //declarations for the low pass filter
    int CURRENT_VALUE = 2;
    double T = .004, w_co, OMEGA_co, f_co;

    hd.bFirstRunRobot = true;



    do
    {

    //This will be to timeout the socket connection
        FD_ZERO(&fds);
        FD_SET(sd, &fds);

        tv.tv_sec = 5;
        tv.tv_usec = 0;

        n = select (sd, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv );
        if (n == 0)
        {

            PostMessage(g_hWndHapticBox,WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
            Sleep(5000);

            PostMessage(g_hWndHapticBox, WM_INITDIALOG, 0, 0);
            Sleep(1000);
            //printf("Timeout..\n");
            //HapticBox(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
            //return 0;
        }
        else if (n == -1)
        {
            printf("Error..\n");
            return 1;
        }
        //  end timeout

        nReadBytes = recvfrom(sd, acReadBuffer, sizeof(acReadBuffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddr, &sockAddrSize);

        //nReadBytes = recvfrom(sd, acReadBuffer, sizeof(acReadBuffer), MSG_PEEK, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddr, &sockAddrSize);
        //if (nReadBytes == SOCKET_ERROR)
        //{
        //  SetDlgItemText(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_STATIC_RobotStatus, _T("ERROR"));
        //}

        if (nReadBytes < 0 || nReadBytes == 0)
        {
            SetDlgItemText(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_STATIC_RobotStatus, _T("ERROR 1"));
            return true;
        }

        if (nReadBytes > 0)
        {
            if (bRobotConnectInit)
            {
                bRobotConnectInit = false;
                bRobotConnected = true;
                SetDlgItemText(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_STATIC_RobotStatus, _T("Connected to Robot"));
            }
        }


        stSend = stSendXML;
        stReceive = acReadBuffer;

        nStartPos = stReceive.find ("<IPOC>") + 6;
        nEndPos = stReceive.find ("</IPOC>");
        stIPOC = stReceive.substr (nStartPos, nEndPos - nStartPos);

        nStartPos = stSend.find ("<IPOC>") + 6;
        nEndPos = stSend.find ("</IPOC>");
        stSend.replace(nStartPos, nEndPos - nStartPos, stIPOC);

        //Raw sensor data
        nStartPos = stReceive.find ("RFx=") + 5;
        nEndPos = stReceive.find ("RFy=") - 2;
        hd.stRFx = stReceive.substr (nStartPos, nEndPos - nStartPos);
        hd.szRFx = hd.stRFx.c_str();
        hd.RFx = strtod(hd.szRFx, NULL);
        hd.RFx = hd.RFx * 0.22;

        nStartPos = stReceive.find ("RFy=") + 5;
        nEndPos = stReceive.find ("RFz=") - 2;
        hd.stRFy = stReceive.substr (nStartPos, nEndPos - nStartPos);
        hd.szRFy = hd.stRFy.c_str();
        hd.RFy = strtod(hd.szRFy, NULL);
        hd.RFy = hd.RFy * 0.22;



                **//...more XML stuff...//**


        //data the is to be sent to the robot
        if (hd.FirstTimePosition)
        {
            hd.RobotXStartPosition = hd.RobotXPosition;
            hd.RobotYStartPosition = hd.RobotYPosition;
            hd.RobotZStartPosition = hd.RobotZPosition;         
            hd.FirstTimePosition = false;
        }



        if(hd.LinearScale == 4)
        {
            f_co = 0.5;
        }
        else if (hd.LinearScale == 3)
        {
            f_co = 0.5;
        }
        else if (hd.LinearScale == 2)
        {
            f_co = 1;
        }
        else if (hd.LinearScale == 1)
        {
            f_co = 2;
        }
        else if (hd.LinearScale == 0.5)
        {
            f_co = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            f_co = 0.5;
        }

        if (hd.Fz < hd.MaxForcePos)
        {
            hd.ForceLimitPosZ = false;
        }
        if (hd.Fz > hd.MaxForceNeg)
        {
            hd.ForceLimitNegZ = false;
        }
        if (hd.Fz > hd.MaxForcePos || hd.ForceLimitPosZ)
        {
            if (!hd.ForceLimitPosZ)
            {
                hd.CurrentZtoRobotPosition = hd.ZtoRobot;
            }
            if (hd.CurrentZtoRobotPosition >= hd.ZtoRobot)
            {
                hd.NewZtoRobot = hd.PreviousZtoRobot;
                hd.ForceLimitPosZ = true;
            }
            else
            {
                hd.ForceLimitPosZ = false;
            }
        }

        if (hd.ForceLimitPosZ)
        {
            hd.ForceZtoRobot = hd.NewZtoRobot;
        }
        else
        {
            hd.ForceZtoRobot = hd.ZtoRobot;
        }

        w_co = f_co * C_TWO_PI;
        OMEGA_co = (2/T) * cTanRad((w_co * T) / 2);

        hd.raw_x[CURRENT_VALUE] = hd.XtoRobot;
        hd.raw_y[CURRENT_VALUE] = hd.YtoRobot;
        hd.raw_z[CURRENT_VALUE] = hd.ForceZtoRobot;

        hd.filtered_x[CURRENT_VALUE] = (pow(((OMEGA_co) / ((2 / T) + OMEGA_co)), 2)) * 
            ((hd.raw_x[CURRENT_VALUE]) + (2 * hd.raw_x[CURRENT_VALUE - 1] + hd.raw_x[CURRENT_VALUE - 2])) 
            - (((2 * (OMEGA_co - (2 / T))) / ((2 / T) + OMEGA_co)) * hd.filtered_x[CURRENT_VALUE - 1])
            - ((pow(((OMEGA_co - (2 / T)) / ((2 / T) + OMEGA_co)),2)) * hd.filtered_x[CURRENT_VALUE - 2]);

        **//more digital filter stuff//**    

        hd.raw_x[CURRENT_VALUE - 2] = hd.raw_x[CURRENT_VALUE - 1];
        hd.raw_y[CURRENT_VALUE - 2] = hd.raw_y[CURRENT_VALUE - 1];
        hd.raw_z[CURRENT_VALUE - 2] = hd.raw_z[CURRENT_VALUE - 1];

        hd.raw_x[CURRENT_VALUE - 1] = hd.raw_x[CURRENT_VALUE];
        hd.raw_y[CURRENT_VALUE - 1] = hd.raw_y[CURRENT_VALUE];
        hd.raw_z[CURRENT_VALUE - 1] = hd.raw_z[CURRENT_VALUE];

        hd.filtered_x[CURRENT_VALUE - 2] = hd.filtered_x[CURRENT_VALUE - 1];
        hd.filtered_y[CURRENT_VALUE - 2] = hd.filtered_y[CURRENT_VALUE - 1];
        hd.filtered_z[CURRENT_VALUE - 2] = hd.filtered_z[CURRENT_VALUE - 1];

        hd.filtered_x[CURRENT_VALUE - 1] = hd.filtered_x[CURRENT_VALUE];
        hd.filtered_y[CURRENT_VALUE - 1] = hd.filtered_y[CURRENT_VALUE];
        hd.filtered_z[CURRENT_VALUE - 1] = hd.filtered_z[CURRENT_VALUE];



        hd.stXtoRobot = dtostr(hd.filtered_x[CURRENT_VALUE]);
        nStartPos = stSend.find ("X=") + 3;
        stSend.replace(nStartPos, 6, hd.stXtoRobot);

        hd.stYtoRobot = dtostr(hd.filtered_y[CURRENT_VALUE]);
        nStartPos = stSend.find ("Y=") + 3;
        stSend.replace(nStartPos, 6, hd.stYtoRobot);

        hd.stZtoRobot = dtostr(hd.filtered_z[CURRENT_VALUE]);
        nStartPos = stSend.find ("Z=") + 3;
        stSend.replace(nStartPos, 6, hd.stZtoRobot);

        if (hd.ForceLimitPosZ)
        {
            hd.PreviousZtoRobot = hd.NewZtoRobot;
        }
        else
        {
            hd.PreviousZtoRobot = hd.ZtoRobot;
        }

        strcpy( static_cast<char*>( &acWriteBuffer[0] ), stSend.c_str() );

        if (nReadBytes > 0)
        {
            int nSentBytes = 0;
            int SendLength = strlen(acWriteBuffer);
            while (nSentBytes < SendLength)
            {
                int nTemp = sendto(sd, acWriteBuffer, SendLength, 0, (const sockaddr*)&clientAddr, sockAddrSize);
                nTempHold = nTemp;

                if (nTemp > 0)
                {
                    nSentBytes += nTemp;
                }
                else if (nTemp == SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Client closed connection before we could reply to
                    // all the data it sent, so bomb out early.
                    SendDlgItemMessage(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_LIST_Server, LB_INSERTSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)L"Peer unexpectedly dropped connection!");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (nReadBytes == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            return false;
        }
        hd.bFirstRunRobot = false;
    }while (nReadBytes != 0);

    SendDlgItemMessage(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_LIST_Server, LB_INSERTSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)L"Connection closed by peer.");
    bRobotConnected = false;
    bRobotConnectInit = true;
    SetDlgItemText(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_STATIC_RobotStatus, _T("Waiting for robot"));
    SetDlgItemText(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_STATIC_RobotInMotion, _T("Robot not in motion"));

    return true;
    //}
}
```

And here is the code for the GUI:

```
// HapticRobot.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "HapticRobot.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE           g_hInst;            // current instance
HWND                g_hWndCommandBar;   // command bar handle
HWND                g_hWndHapticBox;    // haptic dialog handle

bool bRobotInMotion, bRobotConnectInit, bRobotConnected;
extern HapticDevice hd;
HDC hdc;
Handles hc;
DWORD WINAPI DoGravity(LPVOID lpParameter);
DWORD WINAPI DoConnectRobot(LPVOID lpParameter);

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE, LPTSTR);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    HapticBox(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                   int       nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance(hInstance, nCmdShow)) 
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable;
    hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_HAPTICROBOT));

    DialogBox(hInstance, (LPCTSTR)IDD_HAPTIC, NULL, HapticBox);

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) 
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg)) 
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
//  COMMENTS:
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance, LPTSTR szWindowClass)
{
    WNDCLASS wc;

    wc.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_HAPTICROBOT));
    wc.hCursor       = 0;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = 0;
    wc.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;

    return RegisterClass(&wc);
}


//FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)

//PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window

//COMMENTS:

//     In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//     create and display the main program window.

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];          // title bar text
    TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];    // main window class name

    g_hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable


    LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING); 
    LoadString(hInstance, IDC_HAPTICROBOT, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);


    if (!MyRegisterClass(hInstance, szWindowClass))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_VISIBLE,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }


    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    if (g_hWndCommandBar)
    {
        CommandBar_Show(g_hWndCommandBar, TRUE);
    }

    return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;


    switch (message) 
    {
        case WM_COMMAND:
            wmId    = LOWORD(wParam); 
            wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam); 
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
                case IDM_HELP_ABOUT:
                    DialogBox(g_hInst, (LPCTSTR)IDD_ABOUTBOX, hWnd, About);
                    break;
                case IDM_FILE_EXIT:
                    dhdClose ();
                    DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                    break;
                default:
                    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
            break;
        case WM_CREATE:
            g_hWndCommandBar = CommandBar_Create(g_hInst, hWnd, 1);
            CommandBar_InsertMenubar(g_hWndCommandBar, g_hInst, IDR_MENU, 0);
            CommandBar_AddAdornments(g_hWndCommandBar, 0, 0);
            break;
        case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            // TODO: Add any drawing code here...

            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            dhdClose ();        
            CommandBar_Destroy(g_hWndCommandBar);
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;


        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
            RECT rectChild, rectParent;
            int DlgWidth, DlgHeight;    // dialog width and height in pixel units
            int NewPosX, NewPosY;

            // trying to center the About dialog
            if (GetWindowRect(hDlg, &rectChild)) 
            {
                GetClientRect(GetParent(hDlg), &rectParent);
                DlgWidth    = rectChild.right - rectChild.left;
                DlgHeight   = rectChild.bottom - rectChild.top ;
                NewPosX     = (rectParent.right - rectParent.left - DlgWidth) / 2;
                NewPosY     = (rectParent.bottom - rectParent.top - DlgHeight) / 2;

                // if the About box is larger than the physical screen 
                if (NewPosX < 0) NewPosX = 0;
                if (NewPosY < 0) NewPosY = 0;
                SetWindowPos(hDlg, 0, NewPosX, NewPosY,
                    0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE);
            }
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            if ((LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK) || (LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL))
            {
                EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
                return TRUE;
            }
            break;

        case WM_CLOSE:
            EndDialog(hDlg, message);
            return TRUE;

    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}

// Message handler for haptic box.
BOOL CALLBACK HapticBox(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
            SetWindowPos(hDlg, 0, 130, 200,
                0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE);
            hd.Done = 1;
            bRobotInMotion = false;
            bRobotConnectInit = false;
            g_hWndHapticBox = hDlg;
            hd.HapticScaleX = 100;
            hd.HapticScaleY = 100;
            hd.HapticScaleZ = 100;
            hd.MaxForcePos = 160;
            hd.MaxForceNeg = -160;
            hd.EnableForces = true;
            hd.ForceLimitPosX = false;
            hd.ForceLimitPosY = false;
            hd.ForceLimitPosZ = false;
            hd.ForceLimitNegX = false;
            hd.ForceLimitNegY = false;
            hd.ForceLimitNegZ = false;
            hd.filtered_x[0,1,2] = 0;       //low pass output for x
            hd.filtered_y[0,1,2] = 0;       //low pass output for y
            hd.filtered_z[0,1,2] = 0;       //low pass output for z
            hd.raw_x[0,1,2] = 0;            //raw haptic data for low pass x
            hd.raw_y[0,1,2] = 0;            //raw haptic data for low pass y
            hd.raw_z[0,1,2] = 0;            //raw haptic data for low pass z
            hc.Xmm = GetDlgItem(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_STATIC_X);
            hc.Ymm = GetDlgItem(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_STATIC_Y);
            hc.Zmm = GetDlgItem(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_STATIC_Z);

            hc.XtoRobot = GetDlgItem(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_STATIC_XtoRobot);
            hc.YtoRobot = GetDlgItem(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_STATIC_YtoRobot);
            hc.ZtoRobot = GetDlgItem(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_STATIC_ZtoRobot);

            hc.Fx = GetDlgItem(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_STATIC_Fx);
            hc.Fy = GetDlgItem(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_STATIC_Fy);
            hc.Fz = GetDlgItem(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_STATIC_Fz);

            hc.rHz = GetDlgItem(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_STATIC_Rate);

            hc.HapticStatus = GetDlgItem(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_STATIC_HapticStatus);
            hc.RobotInMotion = GetDlgItem(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_STATIC_RobotInMotion);
            hc.RobotStatus = GetDlgItem(g_hWndHapticBox, IDC_STATIC_RobotStatus);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            hd.HapticConnected = false;
            if (hd.HapticConnected == false)
            {

                DWORD nThreadID;
                CreateThread(0, 0, DoConnectRobot, 0, 0, &nThreadID);
                Sleep(100);
                CreateThread(0, 0, DoGravity, 0, 0, &nThreadID);
                hd.HapticConnected = true;

            }

            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

        case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:

            if(IDC_STATIC_HapticStatus == ::GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)lParam))
            {
                hdc = (HDC)wParam;
                if (hd.Done == 1)
                {
                    SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(255,0,0)); //red
                    return (BOOL)::CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,0,0)); //red
                }
                else
                {
                    SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(0,255,0)); //green
                    return (BOOL)::CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,255,0)); //green
                }
            }
            if(IDC_STATIC_RobotStatus == ::GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)lParam))
            {

                hdc = (HDC)wParam;
                if (bRobotConnectInit)
                {
                    SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(250, 255, 5)); //yellow
                    return (BOOL)::CreateSolidBrush(RGB(250, 255, 5));
                }
                else if (bRobotConnected)
                {
                    SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(0,255,0)); //green
                    return (BOOL)::CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,255,0));
                }
                else
                {
                    SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(255,0,0)); //red
                    return (BOOL)::CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,0,0));
                }
            }

            if(IDC_STATIC_RobotInMotion == ::GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)lParam))
            {

                hdc = (HDC)wParam;
                if (bRobotInMotion)
                {
                    SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(0,255,0)); //green
                    return (BOOL)::CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,255,0));
                }
                else
                {
                    SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(255,0,0)); //red
                    return (BOOL)::CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,0,0));
                }
            }

            break;

        case WM_CLOSE:
            hd.Done = 1;
            EndDialog(hDlg, message);
            return TRUE;

    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

There is more code associated with the solution that if it is need I can attach. My thougt was thought to just call the `WM_INITDIALOG` case so that basically it would be the same as closing the program out and re opening it. Any suggestions would be appericated.

Comment: What is the question again? Could not find any question marks :( And trust me, nobody will afford the time to read through all of your code.

Comment: How can I get the Dialog box that I close when my code times out to re open automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Callign WM_INITDIALOG definitely won't do what you think it will. Don't send random Windows messages unless you understand them exactly.

My suggestion, given your design, would be to have your program launch another instance of itself and have the old instance exit. Look into [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN for the details on how to launch another process. I think that this will be the most maintainable and easy-to-code solution given what you already have.

Comment: On the MSDN page that you linked some of the aurguments are otional what should I pass to those if I dont want to use them?

Comment: The descriptions explain what - but typically you would pass 0 or NULL as appropriate.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will look at that and see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making repeated calls to DialogBox like this:

```
do
{
  DialogBox(hInstance, (LPCTSTR)IDD_HAPTIC, NULL, HapticBox);

} while (ReOpenDialog);
```

Where `ReOpenDialog` is a global you set according to the success of your operation (or, to avoid a global, you could use the dialog return result from DialogBox via [EndDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms645472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Also, you don't need a message loop because `DialogBox` calls have their own one inside, thus creating a blocking call (which is why my above loop will work, in fact!).